How to propagate trace context with Dapr PubSub RabbitMq
I have two services talking to each other through RabbitMq.
Service A publishes messages directly to RabbitMq and Service B uses Dapr with the RabbitMq pubsub component.
Both services are instrumented using OpenTelemetry and Service A publishes a message containing the traceparent header as described by the W3C standard but once Dapr picks up that message and calls the endpoint in Service B, that trace context information is gone.
Is there a way to make Dapr take that context form the AMQP message headers?
